# CruiseControl.Net “Duplicate Node Detected” using precompiler

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am working with CruiseControl.Net and am trying to take the dry approach as illustrated in article http://www.zorched.net/2009/01/30/dry-your-cruisecontrolnet-configuration/ I have a simple ccnet.config and a simple projectfile  Test-project.xml.    The configuration valuation tool tells me that “Duplicate Node Detected”.   Any clues/Hints would be great.

Ccnet.config

```
<cruisecontrol  xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <!-- Standard Inits -->
  <cb:define name="StandardInit-block">
    <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet-dashboard/?_action_ViewProjectReport=true&amp;server=local&amp;project=Introvert</webURL>
    <artifactDirectory>D:\CC\$(ProjName)\artifact\</artifactDirectory>
    <modificationDelaySeconds>120</modificationDelaySeconds>
  </cb:define>

  <!-- Trigger run weekly -->
  <!-- Vars $(TriggerTime), $(ProjName) -->
  <cb:define name="WeeklyBuild-block">
    <triggers>
      <scheduleTrigger time="$(TriggerTime)" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Nightly build at $(TriggerTime) for $(ProjName)">
        <weekDays>
          <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
          <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        </weekDays>
      </scheduleTrigger>
    </triggers>
  </cb:define>

  <cb:include href="Test-project.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"/>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Test-project.xml

```
<project name="Test" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

    <cb:scope
      TriggerTime="2:30"
      ProjName="Test"
      ProjStarPath="" >

      <!-- Standard block -->
      <cb:StandardInit-block/>

      <!-- Trigger block -->
      <cb:WeeklyBuild-block/>

      <tasks></tasks>
      <publishers></publishers>

    </cb:scope>
  </project>
```

Comment: could you post the code of the other files please? What is in   <cb:StandardInit-block/> and <cb:WeeklyBuild-block/> might be of use.  Also, i assume this code you have posted is included in another file, could we see that too?

Comment: Both files are included, but the formatting of the first file is less than desirable.  Perhaps you could edit it so it is formatted.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to format XML so ti looks ok, can hints?

I tried enclosing it all in <code><prep> but it still seems to treat it as markup not code.

Comment: just select all the xml and hit the button that has some binary on it in the toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ccnet.config:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"> 

    <!-- Standard Inits --> 
    <cb:define name="StandardInit-block">

        <!--<webURL>http://localhost/ccnet-dashboard/?_action_ViewProjectReport=true&server=local&project=Introvert</webURL>-->
        <artifactDirectory>D:\CC\$(ProjName)\artifact\</artifactDirectory> 
        <modificationDelaySeconds>120</modificationDelaySeconds> 

    </cb:define>

    <!-- Trigger run weekly --> 

    <!-- Vars $(TriggerTime), $(ProjName) --> 
    <cb:define name="WeeklyBuild-block"> 

        <triggers> 
            <scheduleTrigger time="$(TriggerTime)" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Nightly build at $(TriggerTime) for $(ProjName)"> 
                <weekDays> 
                    <weekDay>Monday</weekDay> 
                    <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay> 
                    <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay> 
                    <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay> 
                    <weekDay>Friday</weekDay> 
                </weekDays>
            </scheduleTrigger> 
        </triggers> 

    </cb:define>

    <cb:include href="Test-project.xml" /> 

</cruisecontrol>
```

Test-project.xml:

```
<project name="Test" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

    <cb:scope
        TriggerTime="2:30"
        ProjName="Test"
        ProjStarPath="" >

    <!-- Standard block -->
    <cb:StandardInit-block/>

    <!-- Trigger block -->
    <cb:WeeklyBuild-block/>

    <tasks/>
    <publishers/>

    </cb:scope>
</project>
```

Having just run this lot through cruisecontrol on my box, the only problem i get is the URL in the ccnet.config file.  remove that and the code i pasted above this text works fine.

Comment: Andy,

I got invald xml when I removed xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder".  

<tag></tag>  is the same as <tag/>   in xml.  

What is the name of the start tag you are refering to?   Look at the source again.   It is much more readable.

Comment: I delete the Web line that your mentioned,  but still no joy.    I am running this on my workstation.   My ccnet.config file lives in C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server.    My test-project.xml lives in the same directory.    When I start CC it says…  No loaded type is marked up with Reflectory Type attribute that matches the xml node (#text).     Is it possible that it can not find the xml file?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of CruiseControl? i believe the <cb:scope> tag was a fairly recent addition.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that was it, My CruiseControl was not the latest.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem this week as I also decided to use this DRY approach for CruiseControl.

After starting the criusecontrol service (and it then quickly failing) I looked in the log file (C:\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.log for me...) and I saw something like:

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException: Duplicate node detected: ... (rest of the node that's causing the issue)

That at least gave me an idea of what it was having a problem with.

Comment: Houndey is right, if you look in your logs, it will tell you what the duplicate node is...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was an oversight in posting your xml files here, but you don't have an ending `</project>` in Test-project.xml.